# AppActivate wrd.Name error 5 - trying to Batch replace header image in several MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word, header

I need to update a massive number of documents with our new company logo. The task its just to replace the existing header image with a new one. I found an ancient code that should work with older versions of MS Word but it breaks on 365, so I need the help of a kind soul to guide me as I'm illiterate in VBA.

I tried the following code:

```
Sub ReplaceEntireHdr()
    Dim wrd As Word.Application
    Set wrd = CreateObject("word.application")
    wrd.Visible = True
    AppActivate wrd.Name
     'Change the directory to YOUR folder's path
    FName = Dir("C:\Test\*.doc")
    Do While (FName <> "")
        With wrd
             'Change the directory to YOUR folder's path
            .Documents.Open ("C:\Test\" & FName)
            If .ActiveWindow.View.SplitSpecial = wdPaneNone Then
                .ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = wdPrintView
            Else
                .ActiveWindow.View.Type = wdPrintView
            End If
            .ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageHeader
            .Selection.WholeStory
            .Selection.Paste
            .ActiveDocument.Save
            .ActiveDocument.Close
        End With
        FName = Dir
    Loop
    Set wrd = Nothing
End Sub
```

It should open all files on a given directory, delete the header and paste the one held on the clipboard. When I try to run it, I get error '5' on line 5 (AppActivate wrd.Name).

Comment: Are you running this in Word?

Answer (score 0):

The code you in your question is written to be run from outside Word, probably from Excel.

One thing that you need to figure out is which of the three types of header you are replacing. The code below assumes it is the main header. If you need just the first page header replace `wdHeaderFooterPrimary` with `wdHeaderFooterFirstPage`. You can tell which header you need by editing the header in the UI and checking the grey label.

[image]

The code you have is not well written and can be simplified as below.

```
Sub ReplaceEntireHdrXL()
    Dim wrd As Word.Application
    Set wrd = CreateObject("word.application")
    wrd.Visible = True
     'Change the directory to YOUR folder's path
    Dim FName As String
    FName = Dir("C:\Test\*.doc")
    Dim doc As Document
    Do While (FName <> "")
             'Change the directory to YOUR folder's path
        Set doc = wrd.Documents.Open("C:\Test\" & FName)
        With doc
            With .Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
                .Paste
                'if what you have copied includes a paragpraph mark at the end
                'you may need to delete the last para in the header
                .Paragraphs.Last.Range.Delete
            End With
            .Save
            .Close
        End With
        FName = Dir
    Loop
    Set wrd = Nothing
End Sub
```

You can simplify things further if you run it from Word instead.

```
Sub ReplaceEntireHdr()
    Dim FName As String
     'Change the directory to YOUR folder's path
    FName = Dir("C:\Test\*.doc")
    Dim doc As Document
    Do While (FName <> "")
             'Change the directory to YOUR folder's path
        Set doc = Documents.Open("C:\Test\" & FName)
        With doc
            With .Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
                .Paste
                'if what you have copied includes a paragpraph mark at the end
                'you may need to delete the last para in the header
                .Paragraphs.Last.Range.Delete
            End With
            .Save
            .Close
        End With
        FName = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```